# How to add external styles to Bit dev application or components

Tags: frontend, lit, lit-html, bit.dev

Within bit.dev, how can we import external stylesheets into bit.dev as we have an external styleguide we would like to import into our components within bit.dev. We are only using lit-elements within our application so theme providers are not an option. (Well, still cannot use external stylesheets).

I was hoping we could just import an external link within the .mdx files so we can preview components with the external styles applied. But to no luck. Any ideas or direction anyone can point us in?

Comment: Bit does not support relative import statements to external resources or between components. This means you can choose any of the following; a) if CSS is available via CDN, fetch it from there. b) if CSS is in a package, fetch from there. c) create a component to hold the CSS and import it from that component.

Comment: @itaymendel - a) if CSS is available via CDN, fetch it from there. 
Yup, the styles are available via CDN but still bit dev will not allow for the import within a MDX file for previewing purposes.

Comment: Can you show some code? Does it work in the component composition previews?